# String not received completely on client side

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets

In the below code i am receiving data from the server but the String is not received completely "i should receive a sentence but each time i am receiving a segment of the sentence of different lengths"

```
uint8_t buf[1024];
unsigned int len = 0;
len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
NSString *s;

   if(len > 0) {
    NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    [data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];
    s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",s);
}
```

server side:
i am sending to the server using DataOutputStream

```
 ServerSocket welcomeSocket=new ServerSocket(6789);
 while(true){
 Socket connectionSocket=welcomeSocket.accept();
 DataOutputStream outToClient=new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
 outToClient.writeBytes("sign up accepted you can now sign in"+'\n');
```

Also what if i need to send a long text.

Comment: [Character encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29)! `outToClient.writeBytes("sign up accepted you can now sign in\n".getBytes("US-ASCII"))` Also, it's a good idea to send the String length first.

Comment: Still it is not sending the whole sentence.. yes ill try sending the length first

Comment: can someone please guide me.

Comment: Post your Java code! Unless you're sure it's the Obj-C code that's stopping.

Comment: on the server side, i am just sending this String as a test just to see how it works so no other complexities at the java side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't flushing your Stream. Try something like this

```
OutputStream outToClient = null;
try {
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    while (true) {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(
                connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        outToClient.write("sign up accepted you can now sign in\n"
                .getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (outToClient != null) {
        try {
            outToClient.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (outToClient != null) {
        try {
            outToClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but now on the client side  "len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];"  is not getting anything

Answer (score 0):

In addition to flushing the send side, the receive side is not safe.

TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol. You have to handle the message framing in the receiving side. In your case, you could keep reading until you receive the newline.

The network may split your message to several parts, rather arbitrarily when you look at it from the point of view of the receiver. It isn't really arbitrary, but there are many factors involved depending on the network topology. The receiver has to collect these parts until a complete message is received. This is called framing. One could use the newline for framing, or prepend the length and keep reading until satisfied, or any other solution that lets the receiver know what to expect.